# How to connect Cloud Composer to a Cloud SQL Instance with a private IP?

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to connect to a cloud SQL database from cloud composer with the private IP. However, it doesn't work.

I have tried with a self-managed instance and with a cloud SQL with a public IP and it works fine.

Does anyone have a clue to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To connect to a CloudSQL Private IP instance, you could [create a Private IP Composer Environment](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/configuring-private-ip#top_of_page) and then deploy a [SQL proxy pod in the Composer's underlying GKE cluster](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-kubernetes-engine#proxy) and expose this service using [ClusterIP](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/exposing-apps#creating_a_service_of_type_clusterip).

[Here's](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/connections#configuring_a_connection_to_an_external_database) the Composer documentation where you can find more information regarding this process.